# Generating set of a group and even subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\langle S\rangle$.

Now let $H=\{x_1x_2\cdots x_m\mid x_i\in S \cup S^{-1},\ i\le m\in\Bbb N,\ m\text{ is even}\}$

I'm trying to prove that $[G:H]=1$ or $2$. I started doing this by proving that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. I assumed that $H$ was empty. Which would imply that $S \cup S^{-1}$ is empty which would imply that $\langle S\rangle$ was empty.

Then I proved that if $h_1,h_2\in H$, then $h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$, which was easy because if $m$ and $m'$ are even, so is $m+m'$.

Now we assume that $G=\langle S\rangle=\{e\}$, which implies $S=\{e\}$ which implies that $H=\{e\}$, so $G=H$ therefore $[G:H]=1$.

Now if $G\ne\{e\}$ ? How does this imply $[G:H]=2$ (I know it has something to do with $m$ being even but don't know how to go about it).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Id' like to point out that $G\ne \{e\}$ needs not imply that $[G:H]=2$. In fact, if $G=\langle g\rangle$ is a cyclic group of odd order and $S=\{g\}$, then $H=\langle g^2\rangle=G$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $H<G$ and take a fixed $x\in G\setminus H$. We show that the coset $Hx$ is in fact equal to $G\setminus H$.

Indeed, every element of $G\setminus H$ can be written as a product of an odd number of generators. In particular, $x$ and $x^{-1}$ can.

But then, for every $g\in G\setminus H$, $gx^{-1}$ can be written as a product of an even number of generators, so $gx^{-1}\in H$ and $g=gx^{-1}x\in Hx$.

(The reverse inclusion is not much harder, I leave it as an exercise.)

This shows that $Hx=H\setminus G$ hence $H$ has only two cosets in $G$ and $|G:H|=2$.

Comment: Okay, so all I need to do now is prove that Hx is a subset of G\H?

Comment: Right, but note that this part does not the depend on the precise definition of $H$.
Whenever you have a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ and $x\in G\setminus H$, then $Hx\subseteq G\setminus H$.